# Binding mousemove within mousedown function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to bind a `mousemove` event to a div when the left mousebutton is down, and unbind when it is released. This code should be fairly self-explanatory.

```
function handleMouseDown(e, sbar){
    if (e.button == 0){
        console.log(sbar); //firebug
        sbar.bind('mousemove', function(event){
            handleMouseMove(event, sbar);
        });
    }
}

function handleMouseUp(e, sbar){
    sbar.unbind('mousemove');       
}

function handleMouseMove(e, sbar){
    // not sure it this will work yet, but unimportant
    $(".position").html(e.pageX);
}

$(document).ready(function (){
    
    var statusbar = $(".statusbar");
    
    statusbar.mousedown(function(event){
        handleMouseDown(event, this);
    });
    
    statusbar.mouseup(function(event){
        handleMouseUp(event, this);
    });
    
});
```

The important part of the HTML looks like this

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="statusbar">
        <p class="position"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Firebug says that the bind methods are undefined on the variable `sbar` within `handleMouseDown` and `handleMouseUp`.
The firebug console prints out `<div class="statusbar">` for the line commented *//firebug*.

I'm doing something wrong, probably when binding the `mousedown` and `mouseup`... but what?!
I'm using jQuery v1.4.2, if that helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) are jQuery functions, so you need a slight adjustment , instead of this:

```
    sbar.bind('mousemove', function(event){
        handleMouseMove(event, sbar);
    });
```

You need this (wrap it as a jQuery object):

```
    $(sbar).bind('mousemove', function(event){
        handleMouseMove(event, sbar);
    });
```

The same for the [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/):

```
$(sbar).unbind('mousemove');
```

[You can see a working demo with only those corrections here](http://jsfiddle.net/JLtT3/) :)

Comment: @colinjameswebb - Here's an optimized version, no need to pass `sbar` around, use `this` (the current context) to your advantage :) http://jsfiddle.net/JLtT3/1/